# CrystalReportViewer gives error, "Failed to create component"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

When I try to add the crystalreportviewer to my form it gives me this error

[image]

Before I decide to post the question I check all the cases and try everything but still the same problem.

Here is the startup in my app.config

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Crystal report version is not match on your visual studio and SDK that is install on your machain

Comment: Crystal report : CR13SP26MSI64_0-10010309 and vs 2019